# Returning specific text in excel string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula to get:

appcast

from

campaign_jobboards-hotrod-appcast_32_140_CA-Montreal_d_all_acq_cpa_US-en_lp_transportation_udpmon_Montreal_paid_null_73361

Another example:

snagajob-banner-keywords-imp

from

campaign_jobboards-hotrod-snagajob-banner-keywords-imp_1_20_US-Philadelphia_d_all_acq_cpc_US-en_lp_transportation_null

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove `campaign_jobboards-hotrod-` in the head of each strings and get the word before next `_`. You can try:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-26), FIND("_", RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-26))-1)
```

Note: the length of `campaign_jobboards-hotrod-` is 26.